# Warning function should have a snake case identifier on by default

Tags: rust

I'm trying to figure out what this warning actually means. The program works perfectly but during compile I get this warning:

```
main.rs:6:1: 8:2 warning: function 'isMultiple' should have a snake case identifier, 
#[warn(non_snake_case_functions)] on by default
```

the code is very simple:

```
/*
    Find the sum of all multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000
*/


fn isMultiple(num: int) -> bool {
    num % 5 == 0 || num % 3 == 0
}

fn main() {
    let mut sum_of_multiples = 0; 

    //loop from 0..999
    for i in range(0,1000) {
        sum_of_multiples += 
            if isMultiple(i) {
                i
            }else{
                0
            };
    }
    println!("Sum is {}", sum_of_multiples);

}
```

Comment: This has prompted https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/14738

Comment: Done, had no idea this sparked an improvement to the warning, very neat. Back in 2014' I didn't even know what 'snake_case' meant as a beginner programmer lol.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can turn it off by including this line in your file. Check out this [thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/turning-off-compiler-warning-messages/4975)

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]
```

Comment: @SyntacticFructose -> I would simply accept this as the correct answer. Just because they say you must code a certain way doesn't mean you have to do it. Yeah, yeah I know not following convention makes me a bad programmer - so get over it already. I will code as I please - that is the least I can do in this PC world of designers who have __holier-than-thou__ complexes !! I use these #![allow(dead_code)]; #![allow(non_snake_case)];  #![allow(unused_imports)]; #![allow(unused_variables)] heavily in Rust. I am sorry - but it's the only way my brain works.

Answer (score 14):

Rust style is for functions with [`snake_case`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) names, i.e. the compiler is recommending you write `fn is_multiple(...)`.

Comment: Ahhh I see, does it also recommend using snake case variables too?

Comment: That's the style, there is a lint for *starting* with an uppercase variable, i.e. `let Foo = 1;` recieves a warning, but not a full snake case one like functions.

Answer (score 4):

My take on it is that programmers have been debating the case of names and other formatting over and over and over again, for decades. Everyone has their preferences, they are all different.

It's time we all grew up and realized that it's better we all use the same case and formatting. That makes code much easier to read for everyone in the long run. It's time to quit the selfish bickering over preferences. Just do as everyone else.

Personally I'm not much into underscores so the Rust standard upset me a bit. But I'm prepared to get use to it. Wouldn't it be great if we all did that and never had to waste time thinking and arguing about it again.

To that end I use cargo-fmt and clippy and I accept whatever they say to do. Job done, move on to next thing.

There is a method in the Rust convention:

Structs get camel case.
Variables get snake case.
Constants get all upper case.

Makes it easy to see what is what at a glance.

-ZiCog

Link to thread : https://users.rust-lang.org/t/is-snake-case-better-than-camelcase-when-writing-rust-code/36277/2

Comment: My carpal tunnel disagrees with writing Shift + top-right "_" key 8 billion times a day. I don't force you how to communicate via parameter and function names, so don't force me.

PS: rules are meant to be broken: for example the readability of `get_texture_3D` is objectively much better pattern-matched by the brain than `get_texture_3d`, therefore hardcore snake case is dumb AF.

Comment: Devil's advocate: Isn't `Shift+<some alphabetical character>` pretty much as bad as `Shift+_`? You can map `_` to some unused keyboard character. Autoformatters are great: write how you want and it'll get fixed before you commit and push. Consistent style in a language makes it much easier to use than languages that are stylistically all over the place. Python and Go seem to have done a good job of this. Personally, 3d is much clearer to me than 3D which looks like 3O or 30. But ask 10 different programmers get 12 different opinions I guess...

Comment: My pinky almost rests on the shift key. Shift/uppercasing is way easier (and fewer total keystrokes) than an `_`

Answer (score 1):

**"forNewBees"**
"rust" prefers using snake case in most cases (even in project name).
just like
"java" prefers camel case for functions.

**They 'prefer' and thus, it is just a warning.**

**So what is snake case?**

U will understand if compared with other cases.

**Kebab case?

Camel case?

Pascal case?

Snake case?**

Suppose we want to type a function name.
In almost all programming languages we cannot use "space" in the name.
So we write it in different way.
In your case you are using "isMultiple" instead of "is multiple".
To understand cases I will use a bigger name.

e.g. "function to check is multiple"
here is how it will be in different cases:

```
kebab case:
function-to-check-is-multiple

camel case: (first letter small)
functionToCheckIsMultiple

pascal case: (first letter capital)
FunctionToCheckIsMultiple

snake case:
function_to_check_is_multiple
```

Comment: Or as a simple-to-remember rule: `kebab-case` vs. `camelCase` vs. `PascalCase` vs. `snake_case`.

Answer (score 0):

just insert this in 1st line of code:

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]
```

also to remove some of the most common warning, use:

```
#![allow(dead_code)] 
#![allow(unused_variables)]
#![allow(non_snake_case)]
#![allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
#![allow(unused_assignments)]
```

whole list of warning and error you can ignore is here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/warn-by-default.html

Comment: There is already an answer covering `#![allow(non_snake_case)]`. And allowing all those warnings is a _very bad_ idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is prompting you to change the function name **isMultiple** which is camelCase to **is_multiple** which is snake_case. That's the default Linting for Rust.

To avoid the warning you can either

1. Change the method name **isMultiple** to **is_multiple** or
2. Add the **#[allow(non_snake_case)]** statement just before your method, like this:

   #[allow(non_snake_case)]

   fn isMultiple () {

   ```
    println!("print");
   ```

   }