# How to disable camel case warnings

Tags: rust

This wasn't on google, so I kindly ask someone how to supress this warning:

```
342 |     BAYER_RGGB16,
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: convert the identifier to upper camel case: `BayerRggb16`
```

`#[allow(non_snake_case)]` doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps `#[allow(non_camel_case_types)]` is what you're looking for?

Comment: 1. The obvious way would be to follow Rust's naming conventions. 2. The compiler message includes the full lint name "note: `#[warn(non_camel_case_types)]` on by default".

Comment: @mcarton there are cases where this is needed (externs)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75967588/17576982

Comment: The non_camel_case... did not wok for me, I had to do `#[allow(non_snake_case)]`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're looking for the lint option `non-camel-case-types`. The description of this check in `rustc -W help` is

> | name | default | meaning |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | non-camel-case-types | warn | types, variants, traits and type parameters should have camel case names |

In your snippet, `BAYER_RGGB16` appears to be an enum variant, so the default lint options require it to be named in (upper) [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case). This check can be disabled with the [lint attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/diagnostics.html#lint-check-attributes) `#[allow(non_camel_case_types)]`:

```rust
// Can also be applied to the whole enum, instead of just one variant.
// #[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
enum MyEnum {

    // ...

    #[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
    BAYER_RGGB16,
}
```

[Try it yourself](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=84a3bf496f149632a417669f8482c71b) on the Rust Playground.

Comment: Use `#![allow(non_camel_case_types)]` to disable it for the entire file

Comment: Unfortunately `#![allow(non_camel_case_types)]` does not actually work for me for the entire file.

Comment: @JohnAllen Is that so? It seems to work for me. What's the context where it's not working?

Comment: @JohnAllen add it at the very top of the file and it should work